# Angular js file upload to server via REST call

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

**data** passed in uploadData function contains below value:

```
lastModified:1478845421494
lastModifiedDate:Fri Nov 11 2016 11:53:41 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
name:"u_ex150626.log"
size:2022067
type:""
webkitRelativePath:""
__proto__:File
```

In service.js:

```
function($http, $q) {
        return {
            uploadData : function(baseUrl, data) {
                var fd = new FormData();

                /*for(var key in data)
                    fd.append(key,data[key]);*/

                fd.append("file", data);
                console.log('fd:' + fd);

                var name="Meenu";
                return $http.post(baseUrl+'/data/fileupload', fd, {
                      transformRequest: angular.identity,
                      headers: {
                        'Content-Type': undefined
                      }
                    }).then(
                            function successCallback(response){
                                alert('Response: '+response.data);
                            },function errCallback(errResponse){
                                alert('Error: '+errResponse.data);
                                alert('Error: '+errResponse.status);
                            });

            },

        }
    }
```

In controller.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/data/fileupload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String postFile(@RequestParam(value = "file",required=false) MultipartFile file) {
    try {   
        System.out.println("name = " + file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "OK";
}
```

I am getting null value for '*file*'. Please let me know how can we receive the file from **http request** in *controller.java*.

Comment: you have to use `FormData()` to upload file .....

Comment: I have used fd which is a FormData() object.

Comment: ok , what is your data value ??

Comment: In my jsp,<input class="form-control" id="upload" type="file" name="logfile" file-model="logfile" />. In controller.js, $scope.logFile is passed as data to the service.js.

Comment: add this to `onchange = "angular.element(this).scope().file_changed(this)"` in input